# Fixed Dates for WooCommerce Subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, membership, woocommerce-subscriptions

Is it possible to start and expire subscriptions at WooCommerce Subscription at a fixed time?

For an initiative of a university, I develop a page that should allow payments for semester contributions. There are fixed start and end dates (semester start and end). Buyers then acquire membership in the initiative for the semester. This should work well with WooCommerce memberships, where you can use fixed start and end dates. However, it is counterproductive that WooCommerce Subscriptions can not do the same. If someone buys a subscription towards the end of the semester he/she is a member over both semesters. In addition, the reminders of the extensions arrive on different days. The synchronization of payments is also not a solution, as this allows only intervals.

I have thought about the alternative, to let members purchase a simple product (no subscription, since this must be renewed manually anyway). However, I have the problem that members could acquire several before their membership has expired. I also do not know how Memberships behaves when it expires. Do users have to buy the product again or does Memberships still think the product has been bought?

Comment: I would do it the way you were thinking and not use WC Subscriptions. The purchase of a product for WC Memberships only triggers the creation of the membership account, which will expire when you set it to and then require the purchase of another to reactivate it. Also, it's fairly easy to add code that prevents multiple purchases of a product in WooCommerce.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I solved it that way now. A product triggers the membership. The expire-reminder then happens through the expiring membership, instead of the expiring product. It is a pity that WC Subscriptions does not offer such a function. It is also too bad that WC Memberships does not allow multiple start and end dates.