# Fixed dates for woocommerce subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to solve the following problem:
We are using woocommerce subscriptions to sell offline courses. The course duration is 6 months. Woocommerce subscriptions can only be configured to deduct money from the customer, after he purchased the subscription product. The problem with this is, a course starts on a fixed day and ends on a fixed day. For example course A starts on 01. March 2024 and ends on 01. September 2024, customer A purchases the product on 01. April 2024 and now woocommerce subscriptions will take money from the customer for 6 months, e.g. also in October 2024, even though the course is finished by then.

It's similar to this question:
[Fixed Dates for WooCommerce Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862655/fixed-dates-for-woocommerce-subscription)
But woocommerce membership is not helping because we need monthly payment for our customers